# bigquery, rank before certain string

Tags: string, google-bigquery, rank, dense-rank

i've already tried,

> dense_rank () over (partition by TEAM_CD)

**i want to rank TEAM_CD, before "true" comes.**
Like this!!

```
TEAM_CD     RANK    
-------------------
false       1        
true        2         
false       1       
false       2   
false       3    
true        4         
false       1          
true        2
```

i user Bigquery, Legacy SQL!!
Help me!!!!
(i'm not good at writing English....)

Comment: You need some way to define this order. Do you have another column available, such as a row number? Otherwise there is no way to write such a query.

Answer (score 1):

As Elliott mentioned - you need some way to define the order. There should be some column in your table that you will use to define it. It can be any column of [orderable](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#data-type-properties) type.
Asuming there is a `pos` column in your table - below query will do what you asked (it is for BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  pos, 
  team_cd, 
  DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY pos) AS RANK
FROM (
  SELECT 
    pos, 
    team_cd, 
    COUNTIF(team_cd) OVER(ORDER BY pos ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS grp
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
-- ORDER BY pos
```

You can test / play with it using dummydata from your question, like below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 AS pos, FALSE AS team_cd UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, TRUE UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, FALSE UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, FALSE UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, FALSE UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, TRUE UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, FALSE UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, TRUE 
)
SELECT 
  pos, 
  team_cd, 
  DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY pos) AS RANK
FROM (
  SELECT 
    pos, 
    team_cd, 
    COUNTIF(team_cd) OVER(ORDER BY pos ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS grp
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
ORDER BY pos
```

If for some reason you still bound to BigQuery Legacy SQL, you can use below (but consider [moving to Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql) - it is highly recommended by BigQuery Team)

```
#legacySQL
SELECT 
  pos, 
  team_cd, 
  DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY pos) AS RANK
FROM (
  SELECT pos, team_cd, IFNULL(grp, 0) grp
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      pos, 
      team_cd, 
      SUM(team_cd) OVER(ORDER BY pos ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS grp
    FROM [project:dataset.table]
  )
)
ORDER BY pos
```